# Macbook Pro Mid-2010 15 inch 2.53 GHz Intel Core i5 upgraded clean install to Mavericks and now regularly crashes

Tags: macos, crash, shutdown, kernel-panic

I have a random shutdown problem after doing a clean install of OSX Mavericks (I was running Snow Leopard with no issues), on my Macbook Pro Mid-2010 15 inch 2.53 GHz Intel Core i5. It regularly crashes, my report is below and includes kernels. Would really like an answer as it will shut down at any given time. Normal examples are while I'm using a program, trying to switch programs, open a new program or use a finger gesture on the touch pad. Some days it will run for hours without a problem and then will crash three times in a row inside of ten minutes. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

-Phil

Anonymous UUID: F72B6E6E-4571-57A4-D543-E1441E8549A3

Thu Jan 16 19:59:15 2014 panic(cpu 2 caller 0xffffff7f93252fac): "GPU Panic: [] 3 3 7f 0 0 0 0 3 : NVRM[0/1:0:0]: Read Error 0x00000100: CFG 0xffffffff 0xffffffff 0xffffffff, BAR0 0xd2000000 0xffffff812576b000 0x0a5480a2, D0, P2/4\n"@/SourceCache/AppleGraphicsControl/AppleGraphicsControl-3.4.12/src/AppleMuxControl/kext/GPUPanic.cpp:127 Backtrace (CPU 2), Frame : Return Address 0xffffff8101eeb140 : 0xffffff8010e22f69 0xffffff8101eeb1c0 : 0xffffff7f93252fac 0xffffff8101eeb290 : 0xffffff7f919ca53d 0xffffff8101eeb350 : 0xffffff7f91a96d9e 0xffffff8101eeb390 : 0xffffff7f91a96dfc 0xffffff8101eeb400 : 0xffffff7f91d1b5be 0xffffff8101eeb530 : 0xffffff7f91abad41 0xffffff8101eeb550 : 0xffffff7f919d108d 0xffffff8101eeb600 : 0xffffff7f919cebae 0xffffff8101eeb800 : 0xffffff7f919cfaf6 0xffffff8101eeb8e0 : 0xffffff7f9287aba2 0xffffff8101eeb920 : 0xffffff7f9288a55f 0xffffff8101eeb940 : 0xffffff7f928b851b 0xffffff8101eeb980 : 0xffffff7f928b857b 0xffffff8101eeb9c0 : 0xffffff7f9288fff5 0xffffff8101eeba10 : 0xffffff7f9285bd3e 0xffffff8101eebaa0 : 0xffffff7f92857cc7 0xffffff8101eebad0 : 0xffffff7f92855816 0xffffff8101eebb00 : 0xffffff80112cb873 0xffffff8101eebb90 : 0xffffff80112cd76f 0xffffff8101eebbf0 : 0xffffff80112cb28f 0xffffff8101eebd40 : 0xffffff8010eb6008 0xffffff8101eebe50 : 0xffffff8010e26bb1 0xffffff8101eebe80 : 0xffffff8010e139b5 0xffffff8101eebef0 : 0xffffff8010e1e003 0xffffff8101eebf70 : 0xffffff8010ec921d 0xffffff8101eebfb0 : 0xffffff8010ef3e26 Kernel Extensions in backtrace: com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl(3.4.12)[A4934A66-0E30-36E9-984A-650481102449]@0xffffff7f93245000->0xffffff7f93257fff dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl(3.4.12)[661E3C87-5B97-3272-88FF-B9BA9B6E24ED]@0xffffff7f9323d000 dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[045D5D6F-AD1E-36DB-A249-A346E2B48E54]@0xffffff7f91834000 dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.8)[447B4896-16FF-3616-95A2-1C516B2A1498]@0xffffff7f914ba000 dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.3.6)[38E388A5-92D6-3388-B799-F2498E582287]@0xffffff7f91926000 dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert(1.0.4)[E04639C5-D734-3AB3-A682-FE66694C6653]@0xffffff7f93240000 com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla(8.1.8)[0A1B6F41-168D-307A-BABD-162F3B3C2786]@0xffffff7f91979000->0xffffff7f91be8fff dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.8)[447B4896-16FF-3616-95A2-1C516B2A1498]@0xffffff7f914ba000 dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(2.3.6)[86BA68C6-18DD-30A1-ABF6-54597AD6C277]@0xffffff7f91969000 dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.3.6)[38E388A5-92D6-3388-B799-F2498E582287]@0xffffff7f91926000 com.apple.GeForceTesla(8.1.8)[7DAF283F-6FD3-3783-B3CC-D23964F1B9B8]@0xffffff7f9283a000->0xffffff7f92904fff dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.8)[447B4896-16FF-3616-95A2-1C516B2A1498]@0xffffff7f914ba000 dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(2.3.6)[86BA68C6-18DD-30A1-ABF6-54597AD6C277]@0xffffff7f91969000 dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.3.6)[38E388A5-92D6-3388-B799-F2498E582287]@0xffffff7f91926000 dependency: com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla(8.1.8)[0A1B6F41-168D-307A-BABD-162F3B3C2786]@0xffffff7f91979000 com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDANV50HalTesla(8.1.8)[3666E0FC-87C7-3329-BD8C-2F1ADED100A4]@0xffffff7f91bf3000->0xffffff7f91e9ffff dependency: com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla(8.1.8)[0A1B6F41-168D-307A-BABD-162F3B3C2786]@0xffffff7f91979000 dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.8)[447B4896-16FF-3616-95A2-1C516B2A1498]@0xffffff7f914ba000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: WindowServer

Mac OS version: 13B42

Kernel version: Darwin Kernel Version 13.0.0: Thu Sep 19 22:22:27 PDT 2013; root:xnu-2422.1.72~6/RELEASE_X86_64 Kernel UUID: 1D9369E3-D0A5-31B6-8D16-BFFBBB390393 Kernel slide: 0x0000000010c00000 Kernel text base: 0xffffff8010e00000 System model name: MacBookPro6,2 (Mac-F22586C8)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 1054009050519 last loaded kext at 949133910932: com.apple.driver.AppleFireWireStorage 3.3.5 (addr 0xffffff7f93382000, size 16384) last unloaded kext at 384785366688: com.apple.filesystems.msdosfs 1.9 (addr 0xffffff7f93355000, size 57344) loaded kexts: com.Greatdy.driver.SystemAudioCapture 1.0.0 com.apple.driver.AppleFireWireStorage 3.3.5 com.apple.driver.initioFWBridge 3.3.5 com.apple.driver.IOFireWireSerialBusProtocolSansPhysicalUnit 3.3.5 com.apple.driver.LSI_FW_500 3.3.5 com.apple.driver.Oxford_Semi 3.3.5 com.apple.driver.StorageLynx 3.3.5 com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor 1.9.5d0 com.apple.filesystems.autofs 3.0 com.apple.driver.AGPM 100.14.11 com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager 4.2.0f6 com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver 124 com.apple.GeForceTesla 8.1.8 com.apple.driver.AppleHDA 2.5.3fc1 com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.2.0f6 com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC 1.0.0 com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient 3.5.13 com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU 2.0.4d1 com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver 2.5.3fc1 com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor 3.0.4d1 com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC 1.60 com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet 1.0.0d1 com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X 7.0.0 com.apple.driver.AppleHWAccess 1 com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl 3.4.12 com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl 1.1.12 com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin 1.0.0 com.apple.driver.AppleLPC 1.7.0 com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHDGraphics 8.1.8 com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHDGraphicsFB 8.1.8 com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons 240.2 com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 240.2 com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCardReader 3.3.5 com.apple.driver.AppleIRController 325.7 com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1 com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1 com.apple.BootCache 35 com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient 3.6.0 com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404 com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage 2.4.0 com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub 650.4.4 com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI 4.9.9 com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort 2.9.5 com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet 3.6.9b9 com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331 700.20.22 com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI 650.4.1 com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager 161.0.0 com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons 2.0 com.apple.driver.AppleRTC 2.0 com.apple.driver.AppleHPET 1.8 com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS 2.0 com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC 2.0 com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC 1.7 com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 216.0.0 com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall 153 com.apple.security.quarantine 3 com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement 216.0.0 com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireSerialBusProtocolTransport 2.5.1 com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireSBP2 4.2.5 com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0 com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl 3.4.12 com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily 10.0.7 com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDANV50HalTesla 8.1.8 com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla 8.1.8 com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 2.5.3fc1 com.apple.vecLib.kext 1.0.0 com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.2.0f6 com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP 2.2.5 com.apple.iokit.IOSurface 91 com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily 4.2.0f6 com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily 1.9.4fc11 com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib 1.14 com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert 1.0.4 com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl 3.4.12 com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController 1.0.11d1 com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 2.5.3fc1 com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 2.5.3fc1 com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI 1.0.12d1 com.apple.driver.AppleSMC 3.1.6d1 com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0 com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.5.1d27 com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport 2.3.6 com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily 2.3.6 com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 240.6 com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice 3.6.0 com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver 650.4.4 com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass 3.6.0 com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub 650.4.0 com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite 650.4.0 com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice 3.6.0 com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily 1.7 com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily 1.7.1 com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily 1.7.1 com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI 2.6.0 com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily 3.6.0 com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 650.4.4 com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily 4.5.5 com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily 2.6.0 com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.3b3 com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient 1.0.1b4 com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family 600.34 com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily 3.2 com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 650.4.4 com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM 2.0 com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime 2.0 com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0 com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily 1.1 com.apple.security.sandbox 278.10 com.apple.kext.AppleMatch 1.0.0d1 com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet 7 com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore 2 com.apple.driver.DiskImages 371.1 com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 1.9 com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily 21 com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore 28.30 com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform 2.0 com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.8 com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily 1.4 com.apple.kec.pthread 1 com.apple.kec.corecrypto 1.0 Model: MacBookPro6,2, BootROM MBP61.0057.B0F, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 2.53 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 1.58f17 Graphics: Intel HD Graphics, Intel HD Graphics, Built-In, 288 MB Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M, NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M, PCIe, 256 MB Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x0198, 0x393930353432382D3037382E4130304C4620 Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x0198, 0x393930353432382D3037382E4130304C4620 AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x93), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.100.22) Bluetooth: Version 4.2.0f6 12982, 3 services, 23 devices, 1 incoming serial ports Network Service: AirPort, AirPort, en1 Serial ATA Device: ST750LX003-1AC154, 750.16 GB Serial ATA Device: MATSHITADVD-R UJ-898 USB Device: Hub USB Device: BRCM2070 Hub USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller USB Device: Internal Memory Card Reader USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad USB Device: Hub USB Device: IR Receiver USB Device: Built-in iSight FireWire Device: unknown_device, Unknown FireWire Device: ATA Device 00, Glyph Technologies, Up to 800 Mb/sec FireWire Device: 1394A/USB2.0/eSATA combo drive Device 00, PI-208, Up to 400 Mb/sec FireWire Device: 1394A/USB2.0/eSATA combo drive, PI-208, Up to 400 Mb/sec FireWire Device: Oxford ATA Device 00, Glyph Technologies, Up to 800 Mb/sec Thunderbolt Bus:

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Please use code formatting for Terminal output and logs — line breaks aren't preserved otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

it's a faulty gpu. The issue is well known

http://support.apple.com/kb/ts4088

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a memory problem too …

Try it, and load memory with prime95 to check stability (under heavy load = heat).

PRAM reset and SMC reset are welcome.

Check also (disk utility) the hard disk.

You have to check the pyramid base …
if it is OK, then you can check software issue …

Answer (score 0):

This is a known problem from Apple. I made a program to fix this issue. You can check it out here, it's free and open-source : https://github.com/julian-poidevin/MBPMid2010_GPUFix/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Perhaps you could summarize how your solution fixes the issue?  While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.